# Deleting data from firebase without timestamp

Tags: android, json, firebase

I am working on a survey app and I am saving data like -

Section1-

James-"YYNN"

JIM-"YN"

Section2-

Jamie-"NN"

Sean-"YY"

I want to delete these values after 30 days as I am not having timestamps 
so how to automatically delete this data in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways. Onw way would be to add a timer on client side. If you write this functionality on the client side, it may not delete in time if the user disconnects the internet from his phone. But if you want to go with this approach, here is the code:

```
final DatabaseReference objectToDeleteRef = ...;
objectToDeleteRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    objectToDeleteRef.removeVaue();
                }
            }, 
        30*24*60*60*1000);
    }
```

The second would be to write a function in 
[Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) which deletes the records after 30 days. Then just write a Firebase delete event trigger to call that function.